# Going back to original question after making an edit

Tags: support, editing

Is there a way to see the original question of another user, after making an edit to it, and while it is still waiting to be approved/rejected? If I accidentally miss something in an edit, is there anything I can do apart from waiting for the edit to be rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're under 2k reputation, you will always see your edited version (with a notice at the top) until someone accepts/rejects your suggested edit. If you want to see the original version, view the page in an incognito window.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't figure it out myself :) Thanks!

Comment: [It isn't necessary to shout it out on the internet](http://memeshare.net/meme/Foul_Bachelor_Frog/3294.html)